# How to get the value of checkbox from Dialogue Box to Jquery Var

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-ui-dialog

I made a button which onclick is showing the Dialogue box with Checkboxes .Now according i need to get the value of checkboxes clicked into var of jquery and show it into the webpage as HTML but i am not getting how to do it..

Here is my code..

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<form id="myform" action=""><input type="checkbox"   id="LOCAL" name="LOCAL" value="LOCAL" />LOCAL<br /><input type="checkbox" name="STD"  id="STD" value="STD" /> STD <br /><input type="checkbox" name="ISD" id="ISD" value="ISD" />ISD<br /><input type="checkbox" name="INCOMING" id="INCOMING" value="INCOMING" />INCOMING<br /><input type="checkbox" name="INET" id="INET" value="INET" />INET<br /></form>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Sites',
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            }
        });

        $('#ssites').click(function(evt) {         
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            evt.preventDefault();
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
            return false;
        });

        $('form#myform').submit(function(){        
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                alert($(this).is(':checked'));
            });
            $dialog.dialog('close');
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is working.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ssites">Click</a>
<ul class="insert-data"></ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<form id="myform" action=""><input type="checkbox"   id="LOCAL" name="LOCAL" value="LOCAL" />LOCAL<br /><input type="checkbox" name="STD"  id="STD" value="STD" /> STD <br /><input type="checkbox" name="ISD" id="ISD" value="ISD" />ISD<br /><input type="checkbox" name="INCOMING" id="INCOMING" value="INCOMING" />INCOMING<br /><input type="checkbox" name="INET" id="INET" value="INET" />INET<br /></form>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Sites',
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            }
        });


        $('#ssites').click(function(evt) {

            $dialog.dialog('open');
            evt.preventDefault();
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
            return false;
        });

        $('form#myform').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.insert-data').html('');
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                var Selected = $(this).val();
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('.insert-data').append('<li>'+Selected+'</li>');
                }
            })


            $dialog.dialog('close');
        });        
});
```

You can find this code in the following fiddle. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshmoha/FnmhD/)

To get the values in a single variable. Check this fiddle. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshmoha/FnmhD/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much sir ..one small Doubt i need the values to be displayed next to the link button whereas right now it is coming one line down..

Comment: Use CSS to bring it in a same line.